# Style Only Changes One Tab in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a `TabLayout` within a `CollapsingToolBar` layout. There are three tabs, *Tasks*, *Calendar* and *Contacts*. I defined a style for the `TabLayout` and a text appearance for the tab text:

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

And added them to my `Tablayout`:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

When I run my app, ONLY the first tab text is affected (*Tasks*). Does anyone know why and how I'd be able to make all of them look the same?
[image]

Here is the snippet of code that sets up the Layout in my main `Activity`.

```
    fragments.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Calendar(),new Tasks(),new Contacts()));
    titles.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_task_title),
            getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_cal_title),getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_contacts_title)));
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments,titles);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and here is my `ViewPagerAdapterClass`:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
ArrayList<String> titles;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments, ArrayList<String>titles) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.titles = titles;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return titles.get(position);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason is that this size that you have specified is too large. (and the text can't be shown in one line with this size)
so you can try smaller sizes to see if it applies to all tabs or not.

However if you want to have the size that you want (and don't care if the text may be in two lines), add the following line to your dimen resources.

```
<dimen name="design_tab_text_size_2line" tools:override="true">@dimen/font_size_tab</dimen>
```